# How to chain validation and transformation pipes in NestJS

Tags: typescript, validation, controller, nestjs, transformation

## NestJS validation and transformation pipes chaining

What I am trying to do is to chain two pipes for my NestJS controller, one for validating request body against a specific DTO type, and second for transforming this DTO to specific Type, which is a Type for an argument passed to a service.

### Current controller:

```js
@Post()
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, ProductOwnershipGuard)
async create(@Body() createAuctionDto: CreateAuctionDto) {
  return this.auctionsService.create(createAuctionDto);
}
```

### **Desired flow**

1. `JwtAuthGuard` checks if user is signed in
2. `ProductOwnershipGuard` checks if `product_id` passed in a request body belongs to a product which is owned by issuing user
3. `ValidateAuctionPipe` validates a body passed by user against `createAuctionDto` type
4. `TransformAuctionPipe` transforms `createAuctionDto` to `Auction` type, by adding some properties from associated product (by `product_id` as i mentioned earlier)
5. `Controller` recieves variable of `Auction` type, and passes it down to an `auctionsService`

### Tried solutions

First of all, I am using global ValidationPipe, so `@Body() createAuctionDto: CreateAuctionDto` automatically validates body against this `CreateAuctionDto` without any additional annotations.

I have tried to use multiple solutions like

1.

```js
@Post()
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, ProductOwnershipGuard)
async create(@Body(TransformAuctionPipe) auction: Auction) {
  return this.auctionsService.create(createAuctionDto);
}
```

unfortunately, global ValidationPipe checks body for Auction type, not CreateAuctionDto

2.

```js
@Post()
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, ProductOwnershipGuard)
async create(@Body(new ValidationPipe()) createAuctionDto: CreateAuctionDto, @Body(TransformAuctionPipe) auction: Auction) {
  return this.auctionsService.create(auction);
}
```

this properly validates createAuctionDto, but TransformAuctionPipe recieves empty object of Auction type.

3.

```js
@Post()
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, ProductOwnershipGuard)
async create(@Body(new ValidationPipe({ expectedType: CreateAuctionDto }), TransformAuctionPipe) auction: Auction) {
  return this.auctionsService.create(auction);
}
```

this does not validate a body against CreateAuctionDto at all

4. I have also tried solutions with using @UsePipes() decorator, instead of passing pipes to @Body() decorator, but it did not work aswell.

Here are my pipes code:

#### ValidateDtoPipe

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-types */
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class ValidateDtoPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToInstance(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }

  private toValidate(metatype: Function): boolean {
    const types: Function[] = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.includes(metatype);
  }
}
```

#### TransformAuctionPipe

```js
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, NotFoundException, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductsService } from 'src/api/products/products.service';
import { CreateAuctionDto } from '../dto/create-auction.dto';
import { Auction } from '../entities/auction.entity';
import { EAuctionStatus } from '../types/auction.types';

/**
 * This pipe transforms CreateAuctionDto to Auction,
 * by fetching associated Product and adding its properties to CreateAuctionDto
 * */
@Injectable()
export class TransformAuctionPipe implements PipeTransform<CreateAuctionDto, Promise<Auction>> {
  constructor(private readonly productsService: ProductsService) {}

  async transform(createAuctionDto: CreateAuctionDto, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<Auction> {
    const product = await this.productsService.findOneById(createAuctionDto.product_id);

    if (!product) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Product not found.');
    }

    const auctionStatus: EAuctionStatus = +createAuctionDto.start_at <= Date.now() ? EAuctionStatus.ACTIVE : EAuctionStatus.PENDING;
    const { name, description, price } = product;

    const auction = new Auction({ ...createAuctionDto, name, description, price, product, status: auctionStatus });

    return auction;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chain several pipes like this:

```
@Body(new ParseJsonPipe(), new ZodValidationPipe(createWhitelistUserSchema))
```

Here the ParseJsonPipe will be executed before the ZodValidationPipe.
The value that ZodValidationPipe will receive and work on will be the transformed value from the ParseJsonPipe